# How to structure unit tests in Nim?

Tags: unit-testing, nim-lang

I am looking at the [unittest docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/unittest.html) and I see that I could put multiple `suite` blocks in one test file.

However, I would like to have multiple test files and run them all with a single command. I could write a bash script to compile and run each script one after another:

```
#!/bin/bash

nim c -r test1.nim
nim c -r test2.nim
...
```

But is there a better way? For example in Python I can automatically discover and run all files of the form `test*.py`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put all your unit tests in a `tests` directory, running `nimble test` will run all of them.